# How to add columns showing percentage of total for row based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is how I want my data laid out:

```
CompanyName |No_of_Records |AvgCost |%Correct   |Cat1   |Cat2   |Cat3   |Cat4
```

I can populate the first four columns in a query quite easily but I'm struggling with how to populate the category columns. I am trying to show the percentage of the overall number of records that match the following criteria:

- `Category1 = where AvgCost > Overall AVGCost  AND %Correct > 100%`
- `Category2 = where AvgCost > Overall AVGCost  AND %Correct < 100%`
- `Category3 = where AvgCost < Overall AVGCost  AND %Correct > 100%`
- `Category4 = where AvgCost < Overall AVGCost  AND %Correct < 100%`

Thanks in advance for any help with this. :)

EDIT: Here is an image of the data shown underneath, and the results I would expect it to return above - so the `AvgCost` is just an average of the cost column based on CompanyName (same for `%Correct`)

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: If the condition in this category is true, what is suppose to be returned?

Comment: Hi @sagi thank you for your reply. In each of the category columns, I'm trying to show the percentage of records that match the above criteria (so the 4 columns percentages should add up to 100%), as for each company name, there may be records that match all four categories.

Comment: what is overallavgcost and how it is populated ?

Comment: Hi @LesH I'm not able to post sample data but I've provided a screenshot from Excel that shows the results I'm hoping to achieve - I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi @TheGameiswar I probably haven't explained myself well enough - the overall average cost is an average of a field called Cost based on companyname.

Comment: which should be same as AVG cost populated per company name right ?

Comment: @kidwispa, please edit the question and include into it your sample data from Excel as **text**, not as an image. If you do it, your chances of getting a good answer will be much higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CompanyName ,
No_of_Records,
AvgCost,
[%Correct],
case 
when AvgCost > AVGCost AND [%Correct] > 100% end 'Category1 ',
you can add further categories and conditons like this
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't really solve my issue. I think I may need to use a CTE to first distinguish the overall AvgCost by Company, and then reference that in the case statement to find out the category each record relates to. I then need to count the number of records in each category and divide by the overall number of records to get the % of records that are in each category. I haven't been using SQL particularly long so I'm not sure how to put the query together... :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to get the results you had up there. The avgCost and [%Correct] need a better rounding though.

http://goo.gl/oRfrUp